# How to Auto-Start Server Daemon Without Logging In?

Tags: windows-server-2008, webserver, services

I have just installed the WPN-XM Web server stack on this Windows Server 2008 machine and I noticed that the daemons only start when a session is started on the server (e.g. I can only access localhost while Administrator is logged in) so I did a quick google for "allow registering daemons as services wpn-xm" and came up to [this post](https://github.com/WPN-XM/WPN-XM/issues/57) on the official's WPN-XM's GitHub page, and there are only two posts that read as follows:

> this is a well known feature from xampp and other wamp stacks:
>
> - let the user register/deregister nginx, mariadb and php as windows services via the SCP

and

> will not implement. i do not like services. use scp autostart with autostart daemons.

And the thread is closed. So what does this jakoch mean with *scp autostart with autostart daemons*? How can I make Windows run this binaries at boot?

*Edit:*

So as far as I can see, the author of the thread refers to something that has to do with cygwin and a feature non-native to windows, so the question would be:

> Is there a way to start an application/daemon without the need to start a session, on windows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392891/auto-start-git-daemon-on-window-server

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/cygwin/cygwin_v1.3.2/usr/doc/Cygwin/cygrunsrv.README

Comment: Isn't there a Windows-only solution?

Comment: Not likely one which uses SCP.

Comment: Thank you for your contributions, I'm not so into managing windows servers, I still miss several important bits of information, sorry for that. So back to the question, maybe I have to look for a way to run an application without having to start a session, is such a thing possible? (I have updated the question accordingly). Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use scp autostart with autostart daemons.

This means that you place the WPN-XM Server Control Panel (abbreviated with SCP) into your autostart section. You may do this by checking the configuration directive "Start WPN-XM SCP with Windows?". The server control panel will then starts with Windows.

You may also select the individual servers to start in the "Start these daemons, when starting SCP" section. Simply check the checkbox and selected the desired servers.

An alternative way is to utilize a service administration tool like `nssm` or manually register a Windows service using `sc`.

> So as far as I can see, the author of the thread refers to something that has to do with cygwin and a feature non-native to windows

No. Cygwin is unrelated.

If you have questions or needs support, please consider asking directly over at Github. I'm active over there. That would have been the faster way to get support.